# Microsoft 365 E5 security add-on can't remove autofill email addresses in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, security, office365, microsoft-office-2016, auto-form-fill

Microsoft 365 E5 security add-on blocks the ability to remove autofill addresses. Had a ticket open with Microsoft for 4 weeks about it and they could not resolve the issue. Any ideas?

Steps to remove autofill addresses

1. delete all emails that included this address from Outlook, then emptied deleted items folder
2. started typing the email address into a new email then clicked the X to the right of the entry
   2a. also removed email address from new email using the down arrow and delete button on keyboard
3. removed any contact record with that email address
4. removed all contacts entirely from Outlook
5. added HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options DWORD: DisableAutoCompleteUpdate with value=1 to restore old method of autofill. This registry key is deleted automatically by E5 after a short time.
6. Open Outlook. On the File tab, select Options. Select the Mail tab. Under Send Messages, select Empty Auto-Complete List.

The email address and indeed the entire autocomplete list was successfully removed for about an hour, then it came roaring back with all the contacts.

What is wrong with Microsoft 365 E5 Security Add On that can't get this fundamental function with Outlook working? I have many test email addresses for ecommerce sites that now take precedence in Outlook vs. my main email address. I do not check those test email address inboxes. There are hundreds of bad email addresses in the autofill and it is negatively impacting revenue.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Since the registry key is removed that I added, is it probable that the Azure policy is restricting registry edits? How can I check? 

How do I clear historical data in the Microsoft Cloud Storage that Microsoft maintains on all contacts in all email addresses and text portions of the emails that Microsoft is apparently scraping and storing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tired to use the ***MFCMAPI*** tool to manage your AutoComplete list in Outlook desktop client? If not, that should worth a shot. For more detailed information, check [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/contacts/information-about-the-outlook-autocomplete-list#outlook-2016-outlook-2013-and-outlook-2010).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Thanks I have checked back with Microsoft support and they are investigating this issue. I don't have full access to try it on my own.